# 32 VB appl automating with 32 bit MS Office

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

When running a 32 bit VB application on Win 7 64 bit with 32 bit office, everything works fine.  When running with 64 bit Office (specifically Word), most of the code works fine, but the .Paste method of the Word.selection class fails with 'This command is not available'.  The user can use ctrl-V at that point to paste the contents. How can the VB code be changed to support both 32 and 64 bit Word?

```
oWorkDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(filename, , True, False)
oWord.Selection.Copy()
cell.Select() <--- refers to cell in table in another document
Try
  oWord.Selection.Paste()  <--- failing statement
Catch ex As Exception
  oWord.Visible = True
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Update: the user is NOT using Office 64 bit. He is using 32 bit. So the mystery thickens. Also, the code sequence is used in other portions of the application, and work fine. Also the Try/Catch block has been changed to just ignore the exception and the paste action is occurring.

Comment: It is very unlikely that this has anything to do with bitness.  The error simply tells you that Copy() did not put anything on the clipboard.  Looks pretty accurate, there is no obvious code that selected anything.

Answer (score 0):

> ... selections that include table cells can also lead to
>   unpredictable behavior. The Information property will tell you if a
>   selection is inside a table.
>
> Because Range objects share many of the same methods and properties as
>   Selection objects, using Range objects is preferable for manipulating
>   a document when there isn't a reason to physically change the current
>   selection.
>   Source: [Selection interface - Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.aspx#Remarks)

I advise avoiding use of the `Selection` object as much as possible.  Instead use a typed reference of the appropriate type; in this case a `Word.Range`.  `Copy` and `Paste` are methods on the `Word.Range` object and should be available on a valid reference.  Assuming that `cell` is a `Word.Cell` object reference, use its `Range` property.

So instead of:

```
cell.Select() <--- refers to cell in table in another document
oWord.Selection.Paste()  <--- failing statement
```

use:

```
cell.Range.Paste
```

Comment: Changed to use the Range object in place of the Selection object and the exception changed to "The action was blocked by organization policy".  The document was being stored in a folder that was NOT part of the trusted locations, but added the location to the list and error still occurs.

Comment: @StephenHussey, this sounds like a [Information Rights Management](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Information-Rights-Management-in-Office-2010-C7A70797-6B1E-493F-ACF7-92A39B85E30C#__toc254684671) issue.  Do you really need to perform a Copy/Paste operation?  Try setting `destinationRange.Text = sourceRange.Text` to just copy the textual value.

Comment: Based on my testing, yes I need to use copy/paste as the content includes content controls (active checkboxes).  The Text property would work on just the textual content and turns the checkboxes into just a square.